# SSO using shibboleth and apache for twiki issues

Tags: twiki

I am following `https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/TWiki/HowToEnableSingleSignOn` to enable SSO for my twiki installation.
I am not able to currently make out where and how to define mapping config for REMOTE_USER as per step 6 given in mentioned blog above.
I have edited below config files as part of this exercise -

```
    /httpd/conf/httpd.conf

    /twiki/twiki.conf
    
    /etc/shibboleth/shibboleth2.xml
    
    twiki/lib/LocalSite.cfg
    
    twiki/bin/.htaccess.txt
```

I am able to create/register users and login for my twiki installation and now i want to enable SSO using shibboleth.

Please help me with above query if anyone has done a similar exercise.